# chainer ブロードキャストのエラー

Tags: python, chainer

以下のコードを実行すると

> ValueError: Failed to broadcast arrays

とエラーが表示されました、デバッグするとlossを計算するときに何か問題があるようですがそれ以上がわかりません。どうすれば良いでしょうか？

追記：
 1. https://colab.research.google.com/github/chainer-community/chainer-colab-notebook/blob/master/hands_on_ja/chainer/chainer_tutorial_book.ipynb#scrollTo=A5-zC32qbpQM
 2. http://ailaby.com/chainer_foward_backward/
 3. https://qiita.com/yoshizaki_kkgk/items/bfe559d1bdd434be03ed
 4. https://docs.chainer.org/en/v1.9.1/tutorial/basic.html

```
class MLP(chainer.Chain):
    def __init__(self, n_units, n_outs):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        with self.init_scope():
            self.l1 = L.Linear(None, n_units)
            self.l2 = L.Linear(None, n_units)
            self.l3 = L.Linear(None, n_outs)

    def __call__(self, x, *args, **kwargs):
        h1 = F.relu(self.l1(x))
        h2 = F.relu(self.l2(h1))
        y = self.l3(h2)
        return y


x = np.array([[1.,5.,0.,1.,3.],
              [2.,3.,1.,3.,9.],
              [0.,4.,4.,2.,1.],
              [2.,3.,0.,4.,7.],
              [0.,9.,0.,6.,4.],
              [3.,4.,3.,1.,0.],
              [1.,4.,0.,3.,1.],
              [8.,1.,3.,3.,1.]], dtype=np.float32)

y = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.7, 0.0], dtype=np.float32)


model = MLP(5, 1)
h = model(x)

opt = optimizers.Adam()
opt.setup(model)


for i in range(0,1000):
    loss = F.bernoulli_nll(y, h)
    print(loss.data)
    opt.update(loss, x, y, model)
```

Comment: `model = MLP(5, 1)` の部分は `model = MLP(*x.shape[::-1])` とするのではないでしょうか。。。

Comment: 何故でしょうか、MLPをインスタンス化する際の引数はunitsとoutsを引き受けるはず、、ですよね？

Comment: Variable object is not callableというエラーがでます

Comment: `h = model(x)` としているので、MLP には x の shape の転置を渡す必要があるかと。

Comment: いえ、そこはNONEで調節されるので大丈夫だとおもいます！

Comment: `Variable object is not callable` は `opt.update(loss, x, y, model)` に値(value object)を渡しているからです。opt.update() の第一引数は、マニュアルを読む限り、None か関数オブジェクトにする必要があるので、`loss = F.bernoulli_nll(y, h)` を削除して、`opt.update(F.bernoulli_nll, y, h)` とする必要があるかと。

Comment: そうするとlossが見れないので次のように書き換えましたがブロードキャストのエラーが出ました
h = model(x)
model.cleargrads()loss = F.bernoulli_nll(y, h)
print(loss.data)
loss.backward()
opt.update()

Comment: `model = MLP(*x.shape[::-1])` とすればエラーにはなりません。 MLP に渡す引数が `(5, 1)` で正しいのだとすれば MLP クラスを見直す必要がありそうです。

Comment: しかしこうなると出力が8ユニットになってしまいます。ぼくが望む出力ユニット数は1です。tutorialを見る限りはMLPはあっているはずなのですが、、

Comment: その tutorial は公開されているものでしょうか？ そうであれば URL を教えて下さい（もしくは質問文に追記するなど）。

Comment: 参考にしたリンクをいくつか貼っておきます

Comment: なるほど、、`y = np.array([[0.2], [0.3], [0.4], [0.3], [0.9], [0.4], [0.7], [0.0]], dtype=np.float32)` とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: とりあえずできました！！しかしどこをみてエラーの対策がわかったんですか？

Comment: MLP は正しい、MLP や model に渡す引数も正しい、と考えて行って、残るは y の shape かな、と思ったのです(まぁ、消去法ですね)。

Comment: いえ、そういうことではなくてマニュアルの見方？読み方？についてです。すいません